# Why does this code does not show buttons on different lines instead of side-by-side?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

The following code prints Logo then on next line all buttons side-by-side. In the first `<div>` tag I have tried putting `block`, `inline-block`, and removing the display property entirely. Also tried removing the `Box` mui tag. Nothing works. I am inexperienced in css and maybe making a silly mistake.
Its a nextjs project.

```
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import DashboardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DashboardOutlined';
import ListingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Reorder';
import ScheduleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EventNote';
import ProfileIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircleOutlined';
import SalesIcon from '@material-ui/icons/TrendingUp';
import BookingsIcon from '../../public/images/bookingsIcon.svg';
import Logo from '../mainLogo';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
}));

export default function SideNav() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box>
      <Logo />
      <div display="block">
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.root}
          startIcon={<DashboardIcon />}
        >
          Dashboard
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.root}
          startIcon={<ListingsIcon />}
        >
          Listings
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.root}
          startIcon={<ScheduleIcon />}
        >
          Schedule
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.root}
          startIcon={<BookingsIcon />}
        >
          Bookings
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.root}
          startIcon={<SalesIcon />}
        >
          Sales & Analytics
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.root}
          startIcon={<ProfileIcon />}
        >
          Profile
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try putting `flex` on the `div` with a direction of column like so:

```
      <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column'}}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={classes.root}
          startIcon={<DashboardIcon />}
        >
          Dashboard
        </Button>
        ...
        ...
        ...
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the display block on the button itself,

Buttons by default are inline-block elements and div by default is a block-level element so you need to add the display block to the button tag itself instead of the div.

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<div style={{display:"flex"}}>`

Answer (score 0):

As [@nishkaush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64519299/9449426) said, you should use flex in this case, but since you're also using Material-UI, you can use the [`Box`](https://material-ui.com/components/box/#box) component which provides some css props for you to quickly prototype the styling of the container.

```js
<Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" gridRowGap={10}>
  <Button {...} />
  <Button {...} />
  ...
</Box>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64519195/why-does-this-code-does-not-show-buttons-on-different-lines-instead-of-side-by-s]